# WebView doesn't show content after onPause

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have a `WebView` inside a `RecyclerView`

I configured the `WebViewClient` to run `onPuase()` when page finished loading.

The problem is that some websites (like IMDB) are not viewed, unless I scroll the page down/up, or if the page in stored in cache.

Not working code:

```
getWebview().setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.onPause();
        }  
    });
```

If I delay the onPause, it works (delay time differs between different devices)

```
    getWebview().setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    getWebview().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                           @Override
                          public void run() {
                                getWebview().onPause();
                          }
                   }, 5000);
        }  
    });
```

I also tried `getWebview().postInvalidateDelayed()` and `getWebview().requestLayout()`.

Is there anyway to force the webview to display the loaded content, or simulate whatever happens when I scroll the page?

- I use Lollipop with Android System WebView 43.0.2357.121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to debug or put some logs in `onPagefinshed()` method, you will come to know that Webview's onPauuse() will call 2-3 times before site the 
loads completely in case of URL redirecting.

Comment: Thanks.
I solved it using the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282892/android-webview-onpagefinished-called-twice