# WebView not loading some pages twice

Tags: android, webview

I'm using `WebView` but I have a weird problem. Let's say I loaded youtube.com using `loadUrl(...)`, it's loading, but if I again load same page, it isn't loading correctly, not firing even onPageFinished(...)

Edit: When I load or any other site that interactive and has js stuff, it's not loading twice. **EVEN if I create a new instance of WebView.**

```
Load youtube.com -> OK
Load youtube.com again -> Error, onPageFinished not called, white page
Load google.com -> OK
GoBack -> Youtube.com loaded but still problematic. (Only header and a few views)
```

Manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:vmSafeMode="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    >
```

Here is webView settings:

```
    mWebView.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mWebView.setFocusable(true);
    //mWebView.setAnimationCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWillNotCacheDrawing(true);
    //mWebView.setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setSaveEnabled(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(PrefsManager.getInstance().isSaveAutoFill());
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

   mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(PrefsManager.getInstance().isAutoLoadImages());
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
```

What can cause to this problem? WebView is the main functionality of my app and it was working like a charm until this error.

I am also using WebViewClient and WebChromeClient to override these methods.

```
onProgressChanged, onReceivedTitle, onCloseWindow, onCreateWindow, onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt, onConsoleMessage, onReceivedSslError,  onPageFinished, onPageStarted, shouldOverrideUrlLoading
```

Comment: Add code, where you called loadUrl() and OnPageFinished too.

Comment: Please debug your code and check is pageFinished() called twice or not?

Comment: @KishuDroid, it's not called.

Comment: @AlekseyMazurov I removed everything except of shouldOverrideUrlLoading but still problem. Also loadUrl(...) is basically loading url.

Comment: Try this link's solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282892/android-webview-onpagefinished-called-twice

Comment: Thank you but my issue is very different. Its not called even one time.

Comment: Sorry, not enough data – all settings correct. Show how you called loading page second time. And your onPageFinished method.

Comment: I solved the error. I'm such a stupid, it's not relevant even WebView. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the settings below.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```