# (Android Studio) Progress Dialogue doesn't disappear, when page finished loading

Tags: android

I'm building a **WebView Application** for my blog. Everything is running fine, except one thing. The **ProgressDialog** which appears on the screen while the **Homepage** is loading, doesn't disappear. Even after the webpage is finished loading.

However, it does go away after tapping the screen twice...........any help would be highly appreciated.

I'm pretty new to **Android** development so, a little explanation would be helpful with the answer for learning.

Ps Im using

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 26
```

**my Java code is:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setClickable(true);
        webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        setContentView(webView);
    }

    public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog pd = null;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Please wait");
            pd.setMessage("Page is loading..");
            pd.show();
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

**my xml code is:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My App Manifest code is:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.notherstore.notherrstore">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: That's java not javascript

Comment: Are you sure that `onPageFinished` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onPageStarted()** is called several times, so your **ProgressDialog** is staring several times as well.
From what I found on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25547544/5223744

If the **url** is OK after **onPageStarted()** method starts **onPageFinished()**, but if the **url** is redirected after **onPageStarted()** starts shouldOverrideUrlLoading and then **onPageFinished()**.

> Just place a breakPoint in your **onPageStarted()** and you will see
>   the occurrence.

You can set a boolean which will check if **onPageStarted()** isFirstTime, or you can use the code below:

Just change your **MainActivity** class like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setClickable(true);
        webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        setContentView(webView);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Please wait");
        pd.setMessage("Page is loading..");
        pd.show();
    }

    public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep progress dialog until page load finished, simply set dialog's cancelable false, so:

```
    pd.setCancelable(false);
```